# Counting the frequency of names in two lists (Excel 2003)

Tags: excel, excel-2003

How can I go about calculating the frequency of a names in two lists? I would like the search to go row by row checking both lists at the same time. Using the image as an example, the check would go

```
LIST 1     LIST 2     Frequency
A          A          A = 1
A          B          A = 2 , B = 1
C          C          A = 2,  B = 1, C = 1
B          B          A= 2,   B = 2, C = 1
```

The main point is that if the same letter is in the same row on both lists it should be counted as one.

Comment: This is just using excel. I looked on other websites and they suggested that I use SUMPRODUCT or COUNT IF but I am not exactly sure of what I should do.

Comment: Could you please help me understand the requirements. To me, frequency means to count the number of occurrences in both lists. So, when I see `A` in List 1 two times and another time in List 2 then I'd assume that the total would be `A = 3`. Yet, it seems that you are counting `A` only once in row 1. Does that mean that you are counting a name only once per row (no matter if it is in both lists)?

Comment: Yes, If the same name is in a row then it is counted once.

Answer (score 0):

If LIST 1 starts at `A2` and LIST 2 at `B2`, you can use this formula and copy it down:

```
= SUMPRODUCT( SIGN( ( $A$2:$A2 = "A" ) + ( $B$2:$B2 = "A" ) ) )
```

The second `2` doesn't have `$` so it will turn into `3` on the next row and so on. The `+` is used as a logical or, but it results in 2 for rows where the value is in both lists, so `SIGN` is used to convert it to 1.

Answer (score 0):

If to count the frequency of all three letters I suggest, for a layout as below,

```
 = C2+1*(COUNTIF($A3:$B3,C$1)>0)
```

in C3 copied across to E3 and all three cells copied down to suit.

[image: SO42151972 example]